# Error x064 while registering a windows phone 8 for applications testing

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I just finished a phonegap app which is ready to be deployed on a Nokia Lumia 520.
I purchased a dev account, but everytime I try to register the phone with the registration tool I get this error:

**Status: Error communicating with the Windows Phone Dev Center. Please set the correct date and time on the phone, check the Internet connection on device and try again later (ErrorCode:0x64)**

I closed Skype, deactivated Windows firewall, turned on wifi and manually set date/time on the phone, I even updated the phone, to no avail: I can't register it.

The local machine runs Windows 8 x64.

Comment: Images don't get Googled.  Well, not in the text index, anyway.  In general you should avoid using images to display text here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft closed the registration of Windows Phone 8 devices for development. If you can upgrade your phone to 8.1, you can register it, otherwise you can not use it anymore.

Comment: Really? I'm going to try to update it to 8.1 right now, and come back with my results, thanks!

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I could not find any article explaining that, I spent the whole morning trying to make it work, anyway,thanks again!

Comment: I knew it because I was informed from Microsoft by Mail, but I could not find any verification on the internet to include as link here. They still explain how to register a windows phone 8 device on their homepage...

Comment: Exactly! kinda dissapointed from the start, at least it's working now, marked as the answer and issue solved, thanks!

Comment: I had the same error (ErrorCode:0x64) on 8.1 and it worked only when inserted a SIM card in my Device. Over the wi-fi the registration doesn't work.